# New update on Star Stable says that cards with OpenGL 4.0 or less won't support snow. I see 4.5 on my output and I can't see snow

Tags: graphics-card, wine, star-stable

I run SSO under Wine and PortProton, I don't understand why I'm unable to see the snow when my OpenGL check output says 4.5.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6

It is possible that I am missing something, everything otherwise works impeccably under WINE and PortProton.

Computer specs:
[image]

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-132-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: E2100N v: x.x serial: <filter> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: F2 date: 06/20/2014 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: AMD E1-2100 APU with Radeon HD Graphics bits: 64 type: MCP 
           arch: Jaguar rev: 1 L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: avx lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 3992 
           Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/1000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Kabini [Radeon HD 8210] vendor: Gigabyte driver: radeon v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:01.0 chip ID: 1002:9834 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1024x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD KABINI (DRM 2.50.0 5.4.0-132-generic LLVM 12.0.0) 
           v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD Kabini HDMI/DP Audio vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:01.1 chip ID: 1002:9840 
           Device-2: AMD FCH Azalia vendor: Gigabyte driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:14.2 chip ID: 1022:780d 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-132-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Gigabyte 
           driver: r8169 v: kernel port: e000 bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: virbr0-nic state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 312.53 GiB used: 85.66 GiB (27.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Hitachi model: HDS721032CLA360 size: 298.09 GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
           serial: <filter> 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Kingston model: DataTraveler 2.0 size: 14.44 GiB 
           speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter> 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 185.75 GiB used: 74.73 GiB (40.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: radeon temp: 46 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cybermax-dexter-sdl2-backport-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ppa-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] http: //dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kritalime-ppa-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-lutris-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
           1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https: //deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal main
           2: deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https: //deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com ulyana main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
           2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list 
           1: deb https: //deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free #Opera Browser (final releases)
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list 
           1: deb https: //linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-gimp-focal.list 
           1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/gimp/ubuntu focal main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list 
           1: deb http: //download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./
Info:      Processes: 313 Uptime: 16h 48m Memory: 3.30 GiB used: 1.80 GiB (54.5%) Init: systemd 
           v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 8/9 Client: Unknown python3.8 client 
           inxi: 3.0.38
```